# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Razorpay", referenced from: objc-class-ref in PaymentsViewController.o

Tags: xcode, linker-errors

While I was archiving the app I got this error. Is there any solution to this problem.

[image: error]

Comment: Can you tell me what is `Razorpay`? It's your class or a class from framework?

Comment: It is a framework for online payment...

Comment: Check `Build Phases` of your project and make sure the framework appears there.

Comment: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) I am getting this error...

Comment: Did you check Build Phases?

Comment: yes I have added framework in Link binary with libraries

Comment: How about RazorPay.h file?

Comment: Razorpay framework itself contains Razorpay.h file

Comment: I found solution.. I have installed pod again....

Comment: It’s good. Seem like my answer right on someway :).